# Как использовать id в path?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Я тут новичок.
Можете подсказать, как передаётся `id` в `path`? Необходимо при переходе на `http://localhost:8000/12/` получить страницу участника с `id 12` в таком варианте: `path('member_id', views.member_detail, name='member-detail')`

Вот `views.py`:

```
def member_detail(request, member_id):
    member = get_object_or_404(Member, id=member_id)
    return render(request, 'member_detail.html', {'member': member})
```

получаю ошибку:

```
Using the URLconf defined in firstproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
The current path, 1/, didn’t match any of these.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем urls.py не прописан соответствующий шаблон

```
path('member_id', views.member_detail, name='member-detail'),
path('member_id/<int:id>', views.member_detail, name='member-detail'),
```

кроме того, поскольку вьюшка может вызываться и без параметра id, необходимо подправить и её значением по умолчанию:

```
def member_detail(request, member_id=-1):
...
```

Comment: Нужно было полностью скинуть))
**urls**
`urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('member_id/<int:id>', views.member_detail, name='member-detail'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
`
И **views**
`def member_detail(request, member_id):
    member = get_object_or_404(Member, id=member_id)
    return render(request, 'member_detail.html', {'member': member})
`

Comment: То есть, у меня не получается через path сопоставить число в адресной строке /id/ с ключом member_id, который есть какой-то участник.

Comment: Все верно. django сопоставляет uri полностью. откуда ему знать какая вьюшка будет обрабатывать member_id/id. это может быть отдельная вьюшка. А если будут uri типа member_id/add или member_id/edit/id то это еще запутанней история - может быть одна вьюшка, может на каждую отдельная...

Comment: Я немного понял)) Я вот нашёл реализацию (Я полагаю, на какой-то старой версии) подобную
`url(r'^(?P<p_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail')`
Вот в ней работает ровно то, что мне нужно. То есть, при переходе на 8000/1 я получаю мемберс с 1 идентификатором.
Или причина не в этом? Возможно, мне нужно ещё что-то показать? На этом затыкнулся)

Comment: прошу прощения. в моем ответе uri такой http://localhost:8000/member_id/12 для того чтобы было именно как у вас, надо прописывать path('<int:member_id>'....

Comment: Господи, это работает!)) Благодарю. Буду знать)
Это также работает для других переменных? Указание типа требуется

Я не сразу сказал то, что мне нужно) И потому не сразу получил ответ. Нужно мне научиться говорить о том, что мне требуется) Я пока только начинаю

Comment: тут можно почитать подробнее https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/